# \lstinputlisting will not continue to next page

Tags: listings, page-breaking

So I have this LaTeX snippet:

```
\section{Appendix}
\listoffigures
...
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\caption{MacroCell with 8 AND Gate Arrays}
\lstinputlisting[language=VHDL,numbers=left,breaklines=true,basicstyle=\footnotesize, float=h]{macrocell8.vhd}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\pagebreak
```

I use this template to display my code all the time, but sometimes it will not continue to the next page and centered. I tried many different ways, and sometimes if I move the `\end{figure}` this it works, but today neither worked...:

```
\section{Appendix}
\listoffigures
...
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\caption{MacroCell with 8 AND Gate Arrays}
\end{figure}
\lstinputlisting[language=VHDL,numbers=left,breaklines=true,basicstyle=\footnotesize, float=h]{macrocell8.vhd}
\end{center}
\pagebreak
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `lstlisting` environment (whether used directly or via `\lstinputlisting`) together with the `float` specifier does not break across pages. The `float` key boxes the entire listing into a single unit or block that allows it to float. It does not break the listing into separate floats the with move as a sequential unit. This is similar to the restriction imposed by the `minipage` environment. Even though the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) mentions breaking (and a host of breaking options), they all refer to line breaking, but not page breaking.

So, in order for the listing to break across pages, you could remove the `float=<specifier>` key-value. However, this does not accommodate an automatic (continued) caption for subsequent page-broken listings. This may not be that important (or as big-a-deal) if the listing spans only two pages, since a reader would easily be able to follow the broken listing. However, a listing spanning multiple pages might not be such a good idea.

Alternatively, if you want you could manually break the listing into (at least) two blocks so that neither block is larger than a single page. For this you can use a combination of the `firstline` and `lastline` option:

```
% First part of listing
\lstinputlisting[...,lastline=<x>]{<filename>}

% Second part of listing
\lstinputlisting[...,firstline=<x+1>,firstnumber=<x+1>]{<filename>}
```

where `<x>` is the last line of the first part of the `lstlisting`, and `<x+1>` the first line of the second part of the `lstlisting`. If you are using line numbers in your listing, you may need to specify the line number for the second part, as this may default to starting from `1`. Hence, the addition of `firstnumber=<x+1>` as part of the `lstlisting` key-value sequence. You may also be required to modify the listing caption and specify that the listing continues from some previous one rather than having a number that does not match the former. If your listing has to be split across more than two pages, the same configuration as above holds, with the use of `linerange=<first>-<last>,firstnumber=<first>` for the middle listings.

There is no need to place the `lstinputlisting` environment in a float (like `figure`), since it the package provides it's own form of floating listing (via the key-value `float=<specifier>`).

Lastly, an alternative that should work but is not easy to accomplish, is to actually shorten your code so that the listing can fit on a single page.

On a side-note, wrapping the `center` environment around a floating environment (like `figure`) won't help you either and cause problems. In any case, the outer-most environment should be the float (`table`, or `figure`, or...), with the formatting environments contained within.

Answer (score 8):

instead of

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\caption{MacroCell with 8 AND Gate Arrays}
\lstinputlisting[language=VHDL,numbers=left,breaklines=true,
                 basicstyle=\footnotesize, float=h]{macrocell8.vhd}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

use

```
\lstinputlisting[language=VHDL,numbers=left,breaklines=true,
                 basicstyle=\footnotesize, 
                 caption={MacroCell with 8 AND Gate Arrays}]{macrocell8.vhd}
```

However, if you need it named as a "Figure ..." then use it as

```
\captionof{figure}{MacroCell with 8 AND Gate Arrays}
\lstinputlisting[language=VHDL,numbers=left,breaklines=true,
                 basicstyle=\footnotesize]{macrocell8.vhd}
```

which needs package `caption` for `\captionof`