# How to pagebreak within listings?

Tags: listings, page-breaking

I have a quite big txt file, and the problem is, if I include it with listings, latex tries to put it on one page, but it is too big for one page. So a part is missing. I am wondering, if Latex could do a pagebreak automatically?

My txt file is:

```
*---------------------------------*
*          GARCH Model Fit        *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics   
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : sGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(9,0,9)
Distribution    : norm 

Optimal Parameters
------------------------------------
        Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
ar1     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ar2     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ar3     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ar4     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ar5     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ar6     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ar7     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ar8     0.382810    0.207125   1.8482 0.064573
ar9    -0.554678    0.215585  -2.5729 0.010085
ma1     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ma2     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ma3     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ma4     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ma5     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ma6     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ma7     0.000000          NA       NA       NA
ma8    -0.390819    0.204799  -1.9083 0.056352
ma9     0.551610    0.208866   2.6410 0.008267
omega   0.000004    0.000001   4.0863 0.000044
alpha1  0.078665    0.009643   8.1578 0.000000
beta1   0.907778    0.010924  83.1024 0.000000

LogLikelihood : 7007.315 

Information Criteria
------------------------------------

Akaike       -5.4203
Bayes        -5.4044
Shibata      -5.4203
Hannan-Quinn -5.4145

Q-Statistics on Standardized Residuals
------------------------------------
               statistic   p-value
Lag[1]             3.623 5.698e-02
Lag[p+q+1][19]    23.913 1.008e-06
Lag[p+q+5][23]    28.490 2.919e-05
d.o.f=18
H0 : No serial correlation

Q-Statistics on Standardized Squared Residuals
------------------------------------
              statistic   p-value
Lag[1]            3.598 5.786e-02
Lag[p+q+1][3]    29.381 5.947e-08
Lag[p+q+5][7]    39.060 2.309e-07
d.o.f=2

ARCH LM Tests
------------------------------------
             Statistic DoF   P-Value
ARCH Lag[2]      4.638   2 9.836e-02
ARCH Lag[5]     35.851   5 1.017e-06
ARCH Lag[10]    38.599  10 2.984e-05

Nyblom stability test
------------------------------------
Joint Statistic:  1.9746
Individual Statistics:             
ar8    0.1611
ar9    0.1230
ma8    0.1581
ma9    0.1156
omega  0.8409
alpha1 0.3889
beta1  0.4009

Asymptotic Critical Values (10% 5% 1%)
Joint Statistic:         1.69 1.9 2.35
Individual Statistic:    0.35 0.47 0.75

Sign Bias Test
------------------------------------
                   t-value   prob sig
Sign Bias           0.6522 0.5143    
Negative Sign Bias  0.3228 0.7468    
Positive Sign Bias  0.1376 0.8905    
Joint Effect        1.4975 0.6828    


Adjusted Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Test:
------------------------------------
  group statistic p-value(g-1)
1    20     64.58    7.143e-07
2    30    108.88    3.537e-11
3    40    124.32    7.785e-11
4    50    131.00    2.105e-09


Elapsed time : 1.170002
```

My LaTex code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,     
        12pt,                               
        bibliography=totoc,     
        index=totoc,    
        abstracton,     
        headsepline, 
        ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings} % for ROutput


\lstset{
 basicstyle=\tiny,
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
  keywordstyle=\color{black!40!black}
}

\begin{document}    

\subsection[R Output]{R Output}
\lstinputlisting[float=h,frame=tb,caption=Here is my caption,label=thelabel]{mytxt.txt}

\end{document}
```

This looks like the following:

[image: op]

You can see, that there is not enough space, so what should I do? I would like to increase the size from `\tiny` to something bigger, but then the problem gets even more worse?

Comment: What exactly do you need the `float=h` for? Without it, the pagebreak works just fine :). Oh by the way, your MWE is missing the package `xcolor`.

Comment: @Ailurus I do not know what float=h means, I just used it, because in my previous post it was in the answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114913/how-to-include-r-output-in-latex

Comment: This answer explains your issue quite nicely: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31190/lstinputlisting-will-not-continue-to-next-page

Comment: @ADP What? I do not understand you.

Comment: @ADP not really? You mean under the optimal parameters part?

Comment: @JenBohold Please see my answer to your earlier Q using [`SASnRdisplay`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sasnrdisplay), which just uses listings: code output for this Q looks [1](http://imgur.com/a/MpEf5#0),[2](http://imgur.com/a/MpEf5#1) and [3](http://imgur.com/a/MpEf5#2).

Comment: @texenthusiast well thanks for your answer, but if I delete the float=h it does work. So this is ok for me, or what is the advantage of SASnRdisplay over this solution?

Comment: @texenthusiast ok, your lines are numbered, but this is not that important.